# Display hair thickness in solid view?

Tags: 3d-view, hair

Is it possible to display the thickness of hair particles in solid view mode, for ease of work, or do I have to regularly switch to the rendered view to check? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Blender supports drawing particle thickness in the viewport, as far as I know.